# Using Active Directory only for authenticating logins

Tags: linux, active-directory

Unlike: [Linux + Active directory authentication + only letting certain groups login](https://serverfault.com/questions/159795/linux-active-directory-authentication-only-letting-certain-groups-login)

Which is a full AD solution for Linux, limited to groups.

What I want is:

A simple way a random internal Linux box can use AD to allow logins.

I want this to be restricted, no updates from Linux to AD. In effect this is a ?READONLY? connection.

Examples include:

- No password updates from Linux (you must use a windows machine)
- No other updates or modifications etc from Linux to AD.

Why?  Generally people require ROOT on these Linux machines. These are developers and need to install numerous tools etc. Rather then have local user accounts, would like to have a centrally managed account repository like AD.

(Which our IT group knows and understands well enough - Linux not so much..)

I need USERNAMES + GROUP NUMBERS to be consistent across platforms for other reasons.

I could use YP (NIS) but the IT group likes AD for various reasons.

Comment: Why do you *need* Read Only access? Why not allow password updates?

Comment: Simple every one has root - for business reasons on the machine, ie: they are developers and need to configure setup and install things on the dev machine. And thus I can become you, and you can become me and we can mess with security settings in AD - but if it was "read only" - then none of those security concerns exist.  We are in a bit of highly regulated area of business. (I think it is NIST_800 stuff, I am not in the IT group but I have heard NIST requirements many times)

Comment: Doesn't AD authenticate changes using the users old password?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your company, if you have budge etc., it sounds like you need a 3rd party solution such as Centrify

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that Developers should be able to do *most* of what they need to do on a Linux machine *without* needing root access.
"Configuration"?  OK.
Compiling?  Not so much.

*Habitually* running *as root* is like **disabling UAC** on Windows.  "Easy" but ill-advised.

What's wrong with letting individual Developers log into the machine *as themselves*, using A.D. to do the authentication, manage their UID & GID, etc., and then have them **sudo** to root *if* they need to do so.
(Isn't that the *recommended* way of doing things?)

IIRC, it's possible to control both "shell" access to the machine *and* sudo access via an A.D. Group, so there would be *minimal* hands-on changes required on the server itself.

Comment: im looking to keep things simple. and to support a slurm cluster for another group.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that using "conventional" methods is the way to go.  Hand-craft your own solution and you have only yourself to look to for support.  Stick to the well-trodden path and there will be lots of people to help you on your way.